# Hadoop and JZMQ - no jzmq in java.library.path

Tags: hadoop, jzmq, java.library.path

I'm trying to get the JZMQ code working on ONE of the nodes on Hadoop Cluster. I have necessary native jmzq library files installed under - /usr/local/lib directory  on that node.

Here's the list - 
libjzmq.a  libjzmq.la  libjzmq.so  libjzmq.so.0  libjzmq.so.0.0.0  libzmq.a  libzmq.la  libzmq.so  libzmq.so.3  libzmq.so.3.0.0  pkgconfig

In my shell script if I run the Java command below, it works absolutely fine  -

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath  class/:lib/:lib/jzmq-2.1.3.jar  bigdat.twitter.queue.TweetOMQSub
```

But when I run the below command, it throws Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path

hadoop jar $jarpath bigdat.twitter.queue.TweetOMQSub
```

I explicitly set the necessary files/Jars in Hadoop Classpath, Opts etc, using Export command

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/txtUser/analytics/lib/*
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/:/usr/local/lib/
```

The source code JAR and jzmq-2.1.3.jar files are present under /home/txtUser/analytics/lib/ folder on Hadoop node.
Also, the /usr/local/lib is added onto the system ld.conf

Can anyone suggest, given inputs on what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Add following line to `/etc/profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Reload `/etc/profile` or `.bashrc`.